# Spring Boot OAuth2 authentication with login form

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, openid

i am new to Spring Boot and OAuth2 , i found ressources on github and trying to practice to understand more the architecture and flows, so i have the configuration as follow :

OAuth2Configuration.java

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2Configuration {

@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint customAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private CustomLogoutSuccessHandler customLogoutSuccessHandler;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(customAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/oauth/logout")
                .logoutSuccessHandler(customLogoutSuccessHandler)
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/oauth/authorize"))
                .disable()
                .headers()
                .frameOptions().disable()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/secure/**", "/person/**", "/product/**").authenticated()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/user/**").authenticated()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/user/**").authenticated()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/user/**").authenticated()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/user").permitAll();

    }

}

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter implements EnvironmentAware {

    private static final String ENV_OAUTH = "authentication.oauth.";
    private static final String PROP_CLIENTID = "clientid";
    private static final String PROP_SECRET = "secret";
    private static final String PROP_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS = "tokenValidityInSeconds";

    private RelaxedPropertyResolver propertyResolver;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
            throws Exception {
        endpoints
                .tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients
                .inMemory()
                .withClient(propertyResolver.getProperty(PROP_CLIENTID))
                .scopes("read", "write")
                .authorities(Authorities.ROLE_ADMIN.name(), Authorities.ROLE_USER.name())
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
                .secret(propertyResolver.getProperty(PROP_SECRET))
                .redirectUris("http://localhost:8080/login")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(propertyResolver.getProperty(PROP_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS, Integer.class, 1800));
    }

    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        this.propertyResolver = new RelaxedPropertyResolver(environment, ENV_OAUTH);
    }

}

}
```

SecurityConfiguration.java

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableWebSecurity

public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    // Define the type of encode
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    auth
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {

    web
            .ignoring()
            //.antMatchers("/h2console/**")
            .antMatchers("/register")
            .antMatchers("/activate")
            .antMatchers("/lostpassword")
            .antMatchers("/resetpassword")
            //.antMatchers("/hello")
            .antMatchers("/person")
            .antMatchers("/product");

}


@Override
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
private static class GlobalSecurityConfiguration extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        return new OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    }

}

}
```

CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint.java

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint.class);

public void commence(HttpServletRequest request,
                     HttpServletResponse response,
                     AuthenticationException ae) throws IOException, ServletException {

    log.info("Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access");
    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Access Denied");

}
}
```

what i want to achieve is authenticate users using loging form on browser in order to access protected ressources , but i don't know how in this configuration.
example :
when i access to /product , it shows all products cos it's not secured , but /product/3 for example is protected so it shows a blank webpage with error access denied , i want to show loging form.

when

Comment: It seems like you are looking to create an OAuth 2 client. In the configuration you have shared you only have a resource server and authorization server. Once you add a client you could use [`.oauth2Login()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2) to login through a browser. Furthermore, your example uses the legacy spring-security-oauth project, which is deprecated. I highly recommend using the latest OAuth 2 support provided by Spring Security instead.

Comment: @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana thx for advice , i 'm switching to the last OAuth2 .